# How can i do shape.preventDefault(true); in react-konva

Tags: reactjs, konvajs, react-konva

Related Github issue https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/issues/555

There you can see, `shape.preventDefault(true);`, but I didn't found any way to call this method using React.

***The components I am using***

```js
<Stage>
  <Layer>
   <Text {...textProps}/>
  </Layer>
</Stage>
```

Related docs https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#preventDefault

See

```js
// get preventDefault
var shouldPrevent = shape.preventDefault();

// set preventDefault
shape.preventDefault(false);
```

Where can I get `shape`??

Answer (score 0):

```html
<Stage>
  <Layer>
   <Text {...textProps} preventDefault={false} />
  </Layer>
</Stage>
```